# How do I claim the No Time To Explain pulse rifle?

Tags: destiny-2

I just pre-ordered the year 3 expansion, Beyond Light Deluxe Edition which is supposed to come with the No Time to Explain pulse rifle, catalyst, ornament, and the Any Other Sky Sparrow.

I didn't get any of those items, and couldn't claim it from anyone. I did get the emblem, emote and ghost shell from Rahool.

How can I get my weapon and sparrow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now that Beyond Light is released, Time to Explain is now obtainable. In order to receive it, you simply must finish the campaign and then speak to the Exo Stranger.

---

Looking at the [Destiny 2: Beyond Light Deluxe Edition](https://store.playstation.com/en-us/product/UP0002-CUSA05042_00-D2BLDLXPRE000001) page on the PlayStation Store, the pulse rifle No Time to Explain, along with the other items you mentioned, are not released yet.

The emblems, emotes, and shells you received were apart of the pre-order bonus and were obtained immediately, but the other items not will be accessible until the expansion is released.